# converting time stamp in to readable date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp

I need to convert time stamp in to specific date format (Weekday, month, day, year).

after long search i finally got this code which works in Chrome and Opera:

```
        var options = {
            weekday: "long",
            year: "numeric",
            month: "short",
            day: "numeric"
        };
        var date = new Date(timestamp*1000);
        var convertedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
```

in Chrome i get -> Monday, Nov 11, 2013

so why i don't get same result in Firefox? and how can i fix that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString Firefox does not support the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date.toLocaleDateString is not fully supported by Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

You may consider to use moment.js, that is cross-browser solutin, easy to use and easy to translate

Comment: thanks for reply... but is there any other way to do this with js? with out addons?

Comment: Play with that: https://gist.github.com/shergin/602556
You may also consider to override `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString`.

Both solutions are a bit brutal cause overriding prototypes of build-in objects generally aren't good idea, especially in more complicated projects.